# Python - flask - jinja2 - Dynamically generating routes and functions by looping through values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, flask, jinja2

Hi I am fairly new to flask and python

I am trying to create a simple web app which lists multiple Store numbers and on clicking the hyperlink a csv file is downloaded ( I am getting this data from SQL server - putting it into a data frame and using to to_csv to convert it to a csv on the fly)

**My problem is - how do I dynamically generate the route @app.route("/getCSV/" and def getCSV..)?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below case contains only 2 stores, this could increase to 5- or 100 later on..

I have pasted the code below, I'm using Jinja templating in the html

***app.py***

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, Response
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc


#Define app
app = Flask(__name__)

#Db connection
ikbconn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=xxxxx;Database=xx;uid=sa;pwd=xxxxx')

storelist = ['11','72']


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('template.html',my_storelist = storelist)


@app.route("/getCSV/11")
def getCSV11():
        selectquery = "EXEC temp_POGListSP" + " " + "11"
        data = pd.read_sql(selectquery, ikbconn)
        csv11 = data.to_csv()
        return Response(
            csv11,mimetype="text/csv",headers={"Content-disposition":"attachment; filename=POGList_11.csv"})

@app.route("/getCSV/72")
def getCSV72():
        selectquery = "EXEC temp_POGListSP" + " " + "72"
        data = pd.read_sql(selectquery, ikbconn)
        csv72 = data.to_csv()
        return Response(
            csv72,mimetype="text/csv",headers={"Content-disposition":"attachment; filename=POGList_72.csv"})

app.run(debug=True)
```

***template.html***

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Planogram List for Stores</h2>

        {% for n in my_storelist %}

        <p><a href="/getCSV/{{ n }}"> {{ n }} </a></p>

        {% endfor %}

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need url arguments:

```
@app.route("/getCSV/<int:store_id>")
def get_store_csv(store_id):
    selectquery = "EXEC temp_POGListSP" + " " + str(store_id)
    data = pd.read_sql(selectquery, ikbconn)
    table = data.to_csv()
    return Response(
        table,mimetype="text/csv",headers={"Content-disposition":"attachment; filename=POGList_" + str(store_id) + ".csv"})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Joost, this worked perfectly, all I need to do is put the store list in a config file and I'm set :)

PS - I had already tried the url arguments, but the mistake I was making was putting it inside a for loop iterating over the store list causing the below error:
assertionerror: view function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: getcsv